# ui-grid columnPinned event

Tags: angularjs, grid, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Is there any event triggered when any column pinned for ui-grid?

***Ex:***

```
$scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, function());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api/ui.grid.pinning.api:PublicApi

There is an event `gridApi.pinning.on.columnPinned(scope, function(colDef){})` that is raised whenever a column pin state changes.